# Passing properties using url in TranstionToRoute to new route in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to pass some properties(tableName and currentcpt) when i do transition from controller of a route to another reports route using the following command:

```
this.transitionToRoute("reports?tableName=RT&currentCpt=117");
```

but i get an error that the route is not found. I was wondering what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give model and options to the `transitionToRoute` function.
Have a look at the [API of the function from the Ember Guide](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_transitionTo) .

In your case, `reports` has to be URL of route, not the name of route (**starting with /**). From the guide:

> It is also possible to pass a URL (a string that starts with a /).
>   This is intended for testing and debugging purposes and should rarely
>   be used in production code.

You can prefer other options as shown in the guide:

```
this.transitionTo('blogPost', 1, {
   queryParams: {showComments: 'true'}
});
```